# What is the correct tense for the following sentence?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, conditional-constructions, progressive-aspect

How it is correct to say?

> When the computer was working, the player was playing my favourite songs.

or

> When the computer was working my favourite songs had been playing on a player.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of articles everywhere. (My/The/a/?'s computer was...)

Comment: You need determiners for *computer* and *player*

Comment: corrected. now write please which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the sentences are correct. But they convey different meanings. Your first example,

> When the computer was working, the player was playing my favourite songs.

Means that your favourite songs and the computer were working  and playing at the same time.

Your second example,

> When the computer was working, my favourite songs had been playing on a player.

The song had been playing before the computer started to work.

Comment: And if I said "When the computer was working, the player played my favourite songs.", would it be correct as well?

Comment: @student It's not possible. The simple past is for an action that happened at some point in the past. Your player shouldn't just play a song for a second. The event should be progressive.